# Performing SQL-like set operations on Datatables

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, datatables

I have an array with several hundred elements that are the ids of the data in the Datatable I have created ex, [102,105,155,21,13,225...etc]. 
What I need to do, in SQL like terms, is perform an update where I would inner join on the table rows and the array, and then set those resulting rows to a specific class.

I have attempted with the `.each` and `.find` methods, but I could not get them to work, and looping through the table potentially thousands of times, given the size of the array, is highly inefficient.

Are there methods in jQuery that work with datatables to allow for what I am trying to accomplish? How can they be implemented?

Comment: Are you using a server-side data source? It seem to me that the query operation would be more efficient if performed on the server.  Apologies if I've misunderstood your question.

Comment: Yes, I have the array already, done on the server and sent to the client. I now need to be able to search within the Datatables objects to compare with those ids in the array, and toggle the correct datatables row as already being selected by adding .hasClass(".selected"). How can I enable the feature I am attempting? How in datatables can you search for a specific row?